Ubuntu 22.0.4 LTS Dell XPS 9320 Dummy Output after software update
Sometime in mid-November 2024 a software update broke my Dell XPS 9320 sound drivers.  I have been patiently waiting for a follow-up patch, but so far nothing has fixed the issue.
I am currently running kernel version 6.8.0-49-generic, but the issue may have started when the system updated to 6.8.0-48-generic.  I have tried reverting to each of the 5.x kernels on my system, but sound still doesn't work.
I've long had issues with sound reverting to Dummy Output when coming out of sleep.  I recover from that issue by running "pulseaudio --kill".  When I run that command in the current condition, I see the following in /var/log/syslog:
Nov 28 10:33:52 ubi kernel: [422807.611079] soundwire sdw-master-0-0: Program transport params failed: -61
Nov 28 10:33:52 ubi kernel: [422807.611082] soundwire sdw-master-0-0: Program params failed: -61
Nov 28 10:33:52 ubi kernel: [422807.611084]  SDW0-Capture: ASoC: error at snd_soc_link_prepare on SDW0-Capture: -61
Nov 28 10:33:52 ubi kernel: [422807.611086]  SDW0-Capture: ASoC: error at __soc_pcm_prepare on SDW0-Capture: -61
Nov 28 10:33:52 ubi kernel: [422807.611088]  Microphone: ASoC: error at dpcm_be_dai_prepare on Microphone: -61
Nov 28 10:33:52 ubi kernel: [422807.611090]  Microphone: ASoC: error at dpcm_fe_dai_prepare on Microphone: -61
Nov 28 10:33:52 ubi kernel: [422807.611356] sdw_deprepare_stream: subdevice #0-Capture: inconsistent state state 1
Nov 28 10:33:52 ubi pulseaudio[129606]: Failed to find a working profile.
Nov 28 10:33:52 ubi pulseaudio[129606]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
Nov 28 10:33:52 ubi pulseaudio[129606]: Tried to configure /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0 (alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw) more often than 5 times in 10s

Would anyone now of a manual hack to get my sound back online?

Welcome to Ask. For troubleshoot you could try and run pavucontrol. You will probably need a tutorial first.  Take a look at https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/manage-audio-devices-on-linux-pavucontrol/
